# Activities inside tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity

I have four tabs in my android app and i want to implement activities in each of these tabs, and send intents from the activity inside one tab to the activity in the other tab. The problem is that my classes of tabs extend Fragments, for i.e.

```
public class Results extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.results, container, false);
}

}
```

The function findViewById doesn't work because the class hasn't extended Activity, so I can't attac any activity to buttons. Help on how to do this anyone??

Comment: "i want to implement activities in each of these tabs" -- this approach has been deprecated for over two years. Please use other approaches, such as `FragmentTabHost`, action bar tabs with fragments, or `ViewPager`.

Comment: I can't seem to find good examples with FragmentTabHost and activities. Can you please point me in the direction to look for?

Comment: If by "FragmentTabHost and activities", you mean "FragmentTabHost with the tabs' contents populated from activities", that is not supported. As I noted, activities-in-tabs has been deprecated for over two years. Whether you use fragments-in-tabs or views-in-tabs is up to you, though there is more support for fragments-in-tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) on the `Fragment` to get a view to search through with `findViewById`.

```
this.getView().findViewById(R.id.myviewid)
```